# Why is the axis of a parabola parallel to the eigenvector of 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

Let $\gamma$ be a generic conic in E2.

\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & x & y
    \end{pmatrix}  
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{00} & a_{01} & a_{02} \\
        a_{10} & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
        a_{20} & a_{21} & a_{22}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\ x \\ y
    \end{pmatrix}
    = 0,
\end{equation}
where the matrix is symmetrical.

I have read that in the case of a parabola, (i.e. the determinant of
\begin{equation}
    A_0 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21}=a_{12} & a_{22}
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

is 0) the axis of the parabola is parallel to the eigen space of the eigenvalue $0$ of the matrix $A_0$.

I don't know how to prove this.

My attempt was to think of finding the Eigenspace of eigenvalue 0 as being equivalent to finding the kernel of $A_0$, that is, the solution of the system

\begin{equation}
a_{11}x + a_{12} y = 0, a_{12}x + a_{22}y = 0
\end{equation}
and that the vector found doing this is an axis of symmetry, but it doesn't seem to be a very efficient (if it works at all) or geometrically meaningful path.

Comment: Well, that is true for a parabola with equation $y=ax^2$, hence it works for any parabola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a parabola with equation $y=ax^2$, we have 
$A_0 =\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and the eigenvector associated to eigenvalue $0$ is $(0,1)$, which is indeed parallel to the axis of the parabola.

Any parabola can be obtained from the above one with a rotation and translation. If $R$ is the rotation matrix, the $A_0$ matrix for the new parabola is $A_0'=RA_0R^{-1}$. The eigenvector of $A_0'$ associated to eigenvalue $0$ is then $R(0,1)$, which is of course parallel to the axis of the new parabola.